# How to use both OnGestureListener and OnGesturePerformedListener in GestureOverlayView?

Tags: android, gestures

I am trying to develop an Android application to detect gestures and get elaborate details (getX, getY, pressure etc.) of those gestures using MotionEvent. But to do that both OnGesturePerformedListener and OnGestureListener are not working at the same time. Only the OnGesturePerformedListener is working correctly but it does not show any output for the methods of OnGestureListener. Is there a way to solve this problem? My code:

```
public class AndroidGestureActivity extends Activity implements
    OnGesturePerformedListener, OnGestureListener{

GestureLibrary mLibrary;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_gesture);

    mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
    if (!mLibrary.load()) {
        finish();
    }

    GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.gestures);
    gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
}

public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);

    if (predictions.size() > 0) {
        Prediction prediction = (Prediction) predictions.get(0);
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidGestureActivity.this, prediction.name,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AndroidGestureActivity.this,
                    "no matched gesture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onGestureStarted(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(AndroidGestureActivity.this,
            "STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onGesture(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(AndroidGestureActivity.this,
            "ONGOING GESTURE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onGestureEnded(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(AndroidGestureActivity.this,
            "ENDED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onGestureCancelled(GestureOverlayView overlay, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(AndroidGestureActivity.this,
            "CANCELED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

And the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/gestures"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:eventsInterceptionEnabled="true"
  android:gestureStrokeType="multiple"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/textView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/text_view" />

 </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```